# Eclipse Shortcut alt+ shift + N is working differently

Tags: eclipse

I wanted to try to debug a simple code line per line, but it didn't work because it somehow couldn't finde the file, but doesn't matter.

The problem is, after trying that, somehow Eclipse changed a bit?

Usually when i clicked on a Project, and then alt+shift+N I could choose between different files to create (e.g. new Source File, new header file,...)

And now, it only shows this:
[After entering SHIFT+ALT+N](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuqtE.png)

Anyone know how I can reset it?

It's probably something really simple, but I cannot figure it out.

Thank you!

I tried closing and reopening Eclipse, closing different windows, closing all projects

Comment: What Perspective are you using? That menu varies depending on the active perspective.

Comment: Doesn't it actually depend on what kind of project Eclipse thinks the project is?